# How do you make a slime block on Xbox one in survival?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I followed a webpage that explained how to do it, followed it correctly and it didn't work!!! I put 9 slimeballs into the crafting grid. The webpage then said that a slime block will appear in the box next to the grid and it didn't. How do you do it?!

Comment: Are you playing on peaceful? The wiki says it's only available during [Survival, but not on Peaceful](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Slime_Block)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slimeblocks are a PC version only item, you can not (currently) get them on consoles.

Comment: Not only PC, also Pocket Edition and Xbox 360 too. He has Xbox One.